# Как нарисовать рамку вокруг спрайта?

Tags: python, python-3.x, графика, pygame

Я использую `pygame` и рисую карту. 
Я создал класс `Tail` от `Sprite` и добавил все тайлы в группу, чтобы рисовать все сразу. Теперь я хочу, чтобы у каждого тайла была рамка, но не понимаю как это сделать.

Упрощенный пример моего кода:

```
import pygame
from pygame.rect import Rect
from pygame.sprite import Sprite, Group

# Константы
TAIL_SIZE = 80
WIN_W = 800
WIN_H = 600
TAIL_COLOR = (127, 255, 212)
BORDER_COLOR = (0, 0, 0)
MAP_SIZE = (5, 7)
FPS = 60


class Tail(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int, w: int, h: int, group: Group):
        Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.color = TAIL_COLOR
        self.image = pygame.Surface((w, h))
        self.image.fill(self.color)
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.add(group)
        self.border_color = BORDER_COLOR


pygame.init()
sc = pygame.display.set_mode((WIN_W, WIN_H))
game_map = pygame.sprite.Group()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Создадим карту из тайлов
y = 0
for line in range(MAP_SIZE[0]):
    x = 0
    for rect in range(MAP_SIZE[1]):
        big_x = x * TAIL_SIZE
        big_y = y * TAIL_SIZE
        Tail(x=big_x, y=big_y, w=TAIL_SIZE, h=TAIL_SIZE, group=game_map)
        x += 1
    y += 1

while True:
    for i in pygame.event.get():
        if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    game_map.draw(sc)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(FPS)
```

Я могу нарисовать отдельно прямоугольников по количеству тайлов, но меня не покидает мысль, что я мог бы как то просто расширить свой класс `Tail`, чтобы рамка рисовалась вместе с тайлом

**UPD:**
Я попробовал к классу `Tail` добавить строку `pygame.draw.rect(self.image, self.border_color, self.rect, 1)`. В моем понимании это на каждом изображении бы нарисовало рамочку, однако что-то пошло не так и рамка рисуется только для верхнего левом тайла.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо изменить класс `Tail` так:

```
class Tail(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x: int, y: int, w: int, h: int, group: Group):
        Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.color = TAIL_COLOR
        self.image = pygame.Surface((w, h))
        self.image.fill(self.color)
        self.rect = Rect(x, y, w, h)
        self.border = Rect(0, 0, w, h)
        self.add(group)
        self.border_color = BORDER_COLOR
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, self.border_color, self.border, 1)
```

`pygame.draw.rect(self.image, self.border_color, self.rect, 1)` не сработало, т.к. `self.image` - это по поверхность на которой рисуем. У нее размер `w` на `h` и для всех тайлов кроме самого первого координаты x и y выходят за границы этой поверхности.
По этому рамку надо рисовать всегда в координатах `(0, 0)`. Для этого можно завести отдельный `Rect(0, 0, w, h)` и рисовать его.